# Android custom GridLayout - ImageView into multiple cells

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I am trying to build such a view:
[image]

Supposing that lines represents `GridLayout` and I need to build views 1x1 2x2 3x3 4x4 and 5x5. Views can begin not only from first cell. I can't handle this behavior, or maybe there is some alternatives to  `GridLayout`. To set 1x1 img is simple enough:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="0"/>
```

but how to set one image in 2 cells and begin not from the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

> how to set one image in 2 cells and begin not from the first one ?

You need to use the `xml` attributes `layout_rowSpan` and `layout_columnSpan`.
For an `ImageView` occupying 2x2 cells:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="0"
/>
```

For those using `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`: remember to change `android` to `app` where "app" is your XML namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Note that you can omit the attributes `layout_width` and `layout_height` because with `GridLayout` they are not required (and will make no difference).

For further information see also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or the article on [http://android-developers.blogspot.de](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)